# Execute part of the code in 32bit and other part from 64bit power-shell in one session

Tags: powershell

I am starting a powershell session to a remote computer(oracle db server), to execute some queries.Before the actual deployment, there are some pre-deployment tests that are executed like checking if connection to the database is ok, ssh connection is ok, sftp.. In that session a lot of powershell scripts are getting called. I'll try to explain the flow as much as possible. First of all, we are loading those PS scripts we use later like this:

```
LogInfo("Load DatabaseActions")
$incFile = Resolve-Path .\deployment\DatabaseActions.ps1
. $incFile
                    
Write-Host "Setup Environment"
LogInfo("Load SSH")
$incFile = Resolve-Path .\deployment\SSH.ps1
```

This is part of the code from the **DatabaseActions.ps1**:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\somePath\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" 
Function TestDBConnection($connectString)
{
  //Code for opening a connection to the database
}
```

After scripts are loaded, tests are getting executed one by one. There is a separate script for each test(db connection, ssh, sftp). First test is for connection to the database. There is a scripts called **DatabaseConnectionTest.ps1** where I am just calling a function from **DatabaseActions.ps1** :

```
$Result = TestDBConnection $RunSettings.ConnectionString
```

The problem here is that **Oracle-Client.dll** needs to be executed in a 32bit powershell and the other tests in 64bit powershell. When I start a 64bit session, Oracle dll is not loaded correctly. When I start a 32bit powershell, Oracle dll is good, but then it falls on ssh test since I am using a 64bit ssh client.I need to somehow switch between 32bit and 64bit powershell but without breaking something. :)I don't know if that is possible.

I tried creating an alias when starting the 64bit session like this :

```
Set-Alias Start-PowerShell32 "$env:windir\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
```

and then wrap the code in  **DatabaseActions.ps1** like this:

```
Start-PowerShell32 { 
Add-Type -Path "C:\somePath\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" 
Function TestDBConnection($connectString)
{
  //Code for opening a connection to the database
} }
```

It is not working since it is a new session and it does not know the **TestDBConnection** function.

Do you have some idea how I can fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: "There is a separate script for each test" - I'm not sure I understand the issue here - if the test that needs to run in a 32-bit process is already contained in it's own script, why not just do `Start-PowerShell32 C:\Path\To\32bit\script.ps1`?

Comment: Separate power-shell script for each test. It means when DatabaseConnectionTest.ps1  finish its job, next on the list is TestSshConnection.ps1 and so on. They are getting executed one by one in one session which is 64bit. I need first one to be executed in 32bit process. Can you please explain more in detail what do you mean by`Start-PowerShell32 C:\Path\To\32bit\script.ps1` ?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I think what is confusing to me is that I don't know where exactly to do the Start-PowerShell32. I have tried to do it in DatabaseActions.ps1 like I explained above but then TestDBConnection is not recognized. Are you suggesting I should wrap this code `$Result = TestDBConnection $RunSettings.ConnectionString` in `Start-PowerShell32` ? I guess the whole script ` DatabaseActions.ps1` should be loaded first in 32bit process, but I am not sure where and how.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have 64-bit components?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart  Of course It does but unfortunately installing the 64bit version is not an option.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart --- [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/odac-downloads.html)   ---   [Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (x64) 64-bit](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html)

Comment: @Andrej, why not consider using jobs for each run? Run the x32 job, watch for its completion, then od the next thing.

Comment: @postanote Right, that was my point, but the OP says that installing them is not an option (but did not say _why_ that's not an option).

Comment: @postanote I am pretty new to power-shell and jobs are not something familiar to me but will have a look, thanks.